# React : make backend API call when user is authenticated, use LocalStorage if not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a small note taking app with React and Node.js (Express). If the user is authenticated I make API calls to the backend to fetch, create, update, delete notes persisted in a MongoDB database. If he's not, the notes are stored in localStorage. I have an AuthContext with login, logout and signup functions.
I can know if the user is loggedIn with my useAuth() custom hook in my AuthContext :

```
const { user } = useAuth();
```

And I have a separate file to make the API calls that I use in my components (getNotes, createNotes ...)

I fetch my notes in the useEffect hook

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const notes: Note[] = getNotes();
  setNotes(notes);
}, []);
```

And I render my notes like this (simplified)

```
{notes.length > 0 && (
    <ul>{notes.map(renderNote)}</ul>
  )}

  const renderNote = (note) => {
    return (
      <Note note={note} />
    );
  };
```

My question is what would be a good practice to implement the different behaviors (API calls or localStorage) ?

I can add a parameter isLoggedIn to the functions and add an if statement inside the function like this (simplified version) :

```
const getNotes = (isLoggedIn) => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return notes = fetch("/notes")
    } else {
      return notes = localStorage.getItem("notes")
    }
}
```

But this does not look like something clean to do if I have do to this in every function.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use-case of polymorphism / multiple classes implementing the same interface.

Comment: I was thinking to surround the ` fetch('/notes")` in a try catch, and when the exception is fired (nodeJS check maybe a token) the catch block will use the localStorage method instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could do.  I think I'd suggest you create the idea of some store that implements a simple getter/setter interface, then have your `useAuth` hook return the correct store depending on the auth state.  If authenticated, then your hook returns the remote store.  If not, then it returns the local storage store.  But your store looks the same to your component no matter whether it's a local or remote store.

Now your code can just call get/set on the store and not care about where your info is stored or even whether the user is logged in. A main goal is to avoid having a lot of `if (loggedIn) { ... }` code all over your app.

Something like...

```
const useLocalStorageStore = () => {
  const get = (key) => {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  };
  const set = (key, value) => {
    // I append 'local' here just to make it obvious the 
    // local store is in use in this example
    localStorage.setItem(key, `${value} local`);
  };
  return { get, set };
};

// This contrived example uses localStorage too to make my example easier,
// but you'd add the fetch business to your get/set methods
// here in this remote store.
const useRemoteStore = () => {
  const baseUrl = "http://localhost/foo/bar";
  const get = async (key) => {
    //return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${key}`);
    // really should fetch here, but for this example use local
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  };
  const set = async (key, value) => {
    // I append 'remote' here just to make it obvious the 
    // remote store is in use in this example
    localStorage.setItem(key, `${value} remote`);
  };
  return { get, set };
};


const useAuth = () => {
  // AuthContext is your source of loggedIn info, 
  // however you have it available in your app.
  const { login, logout, loggedIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const authedStore = useRemoteStore();
  const unauthedStore = useLocalStorageStore();
  const store = loggedIn ? authedStore : unauthedStore;

  return { login, logout, loggedIn, store };
};
```

At this point, the `store` has all you need to get or set key values.  Then you can use it in your components with...

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loggedIn, login, logout, store } = useAuth();

  const setNotesValue = async (value) => {
    // Your store handles communicating with the correct back end.
    await store.set("notes", value);
  };

  const getNotesValue = async () => {
    // Your store handles communicating with the correct back end.
    const value = await store.get("notes");
  };

  return (
    <div>Your UI...</div>
  );
};
```

Here's a sandbox to demo this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-gould-v1qe0

Comment: Thanks. But the problem I see here is that my functions to fetch the notes are in a helper file, not inside the component, so I won't be able to use the context to choose the store because it is outside the component. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: This is to use local vs remote store. In my case, I always need to use remote only. Any way to hold all API calls in any component in whole app until use is authenticated?